# How to compare dates in a query with previous month dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to write a query in oracle for which I have a table A, I want to find Transfer in course. In this requirement I have to compare Feb data with Jan and produce another column with Y or N results.

```
ID     Date          Course1    Course2
123    01-JAN-2010   2000       3500
123    01-FEB-2010   2000       3500
123    01-MAR-2010   2500       3500
123    01-APR-2010   2000       3500
123    01-MAY-2010   2000       3000
123    01-JUN-2010   2000       3500
```

Requirement: If course1 <> previous month course1 or 
                course2 <> previous month course2 
             then Y
             else N

Expected Results:

```
ID     Date          Course1    Course2   Transfer
123    01-JAN-2010   2000       3500      
123    01-FEB-2010   2000       3500      N
123    01-MAR-2010   2500       3500      Y
123    01-APR-2010   2000       3500      Y
123    01-MAY-2010   2000       3000      Y
123    01-JUN-2010   2000       3000      N
```

My Query:

```
select a.ID, a.Date, a.Course1, a.Course2,

case when (a.Course1 <> (select b.Course1 from TableA b where b.Date = add_months(a.Date-1) and b.ID = a.ID )  or a.Course2 <> (select b.Course2 from TableA b where b.Date = add_months(a.Date-1) and b.ID = a.ID ) )
        then Y
    else N
end  as Transfer

from TableA a
where a.ID = '123';
```

But this query I am getting error or invalid arguments....

Need help to correct the query or any other approach to get required results.

Thanks

Adding------

if you can use this data you will see what issue I am getting

```
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-JAN-2010', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-FEB-2010', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-MAR-2010', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-APR-2010', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-MAY-2010', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-JUN-2010', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-JUL-2010', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-AUG-2010', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-SEP-2010', 2500, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-OCT-2010', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-NOV-2010', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-DEC-2010', 2000, NULL);

insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-JAN-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-FEB-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-MAR-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-APR-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-MAY-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-JUN-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-JUL-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-AUG-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-SEP-2011', 2500, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-OCT-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-NOV-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-DEC-2011', 2000, NULL);

insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-JAN-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-FEB-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-MAR-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-APR-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-MAY-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-JUN-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-JUL-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-AUG-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-SEP-2012', 2500, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-OCT-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-NOV-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (123,'01-DEC-2012', 2000, NULL);


insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-JAN-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-FEB-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-MAR-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-APR-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-MAY-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-JUN-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-JUL-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-AUG-2011', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-SEP-2011', 2500, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-OCT-2011', 2500, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-NOV-2011', 2500, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-DEC-2011', 2500, NULL);

insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-JAN-2012', 2500, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-FEB-2012', 2500, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-MAR-2012', 25000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-APR-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-MAY-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-JUN-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-JUL-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-AUG-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-SEP-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-OCT-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-NOV-2012', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-DEC-2012', 2000, NULL);

insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-JAN-2013', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-FEB-2013', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-MAR-2013', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-APR-2013', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-MAY-2013', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-JUN-2013', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-JUL-2013', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-AUG-2013', 2000, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-SEP-2013', 2500, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-OCT-2013', 2500, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-NOV-2013', 2500, NULL);
insert into TableA (idd, datee, course1, course2) values (456,'01-DEC-2013', 2500, NULL);
```

my query

```
select idd, datee, course1, course2, 
  case when (course1 <> lag(course1,1,course1) over (order by datee)) or
        (course2 <> lag(course2,1,course2) over (order by datee)) 
  then 'Y' else 'N' end as transfer
 from tableA 
  where idd in ('123', '456')
 order by idd, datee;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In oracle there is function lag.

```
select id, date, course1, course2, 
  case when (course1 <> lag(course1,1,course1) over (order by date)) or
            (course2 <> lag(course2,1,course2) over (order by date)) 
  then 'Y' else 'N' end as transfer
  from tableA 
  order by date;
```

EDIT

```
select idd, datee, course1, course2, 
  case when (course1 <> lag(course1,1,course1) over (order by idd, datee)) or
        (course2 <> lag(course2,1,course2) over (order by idd, datee)) 
  then 'Y' else 'N' end as transfer
 from tableA 
  where idd in ('123', '456')
 order by idd, datee;
```

Comment: Now I need to update this query for multiple ID in a table with different dates sequence of dates in it. could you please advice on it

Comment: @Qasim0787 but this query works for all dates you have in the table. So what's the matter?

Comment: I added two id's as example up. if you can create table and try you will see what issue I am getting.

Comment: @Qasim0787 I've posted you edited answer. If you added another column to order by you need to add it as well in lag definition. My first query was working only for singly idd. Try now

Comment: Great...Perfect